# Let f be a continuous real valued function defined on the compact space X.

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a continuous real valued function defined on the compact space X.

I showed that $m:=\inf_{x\in X} f(x)$ is a finite number.

1) I need to show that there exists a sequence $x_n \in X$ such that $f(x_n)->m$
and 
2) There exists a point $ \bar x \in X$  bar such that $f(\bar x )=m$
Answer 1) Now I did  say that since f[X] is a compact space, as the continuous image of a compact space. And since f[X] is compact then it is sequentially compact and thus every sequence $f(x_n)$ in $f[X]$ has a converging sub-sequence $f(x_{n_k})->m$ BUT, I need to prove that m is one of the limit points, How do I do that?
Answer 2)I don't know what to do?

Comment: It's not true that *every* sequence $f(x_n)$ has a subsequence whose limit is $m$. But there is at least *one* such sequence, because $m$ is the infimum of values of $f$; if there weren't such a sequence, then we could pick a bigger $m$ to be the lower bound.

Comment: @ Christopher Thank you for pointing out my pitfall.SO is  this how I prove that m is one of the limit points?

Comment: @ Christopher  So are you saying that each point in f[X] is a limit point of some subsequence?

Comment: @Klara, perhaps it is time now that you upvote all the answers that you liked and *accept* the one you think is best of them all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will explain how to construct the sequence for part (1). You will need to use the compactness property, as you mentioned, to finish the rest of the problem. By definition $m$ is the *greatest lower bound* for the set of values of $f$. This means that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there must exist $x \in X$ such that $f(x) < m + \epsilon$. To see this, suppose $x$ didn't exist. Then $m + \epsilon$ would be a lower bound for $f$, and it is bigger than $m$, so then $m$ wouldn't be the greatest lower bound, a contradiction.

Then, in particular, if $\epsilon = 1/n$, there exists $x_n \in X$ such that $f(x_n) < m + 1/n$. Furthermore, $f(x_n) \geq m$, so we have
$$ m \le f(x_n) < m + 1/n$$
so $f(x_n) \rightarrow m$ by applying the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

You can use the definition of infimum:

$$m=\inf_{x\in X}f(x)\iff \forall \,\epsilon >0\;\exists\,x_\epsilon\in X\;\;s.t.\;\;m\le f(x_\epsilon)<m+\epsilon$$

Now construct carefully a sequence $\,x_n\,$ choosing each time $\,\epsilon=\frac{1}{n}\,$ , for example:

$$x_1\in X\;\;s.t.\;\;m\le f(x_1)<m-1$$

$$x_2\in X\;\;s.t.\;\;m\le f(x_2)<\min\left\{m-\frac{1}{2}\;,\;f(x_1)\right\}$$

$$x_3\in X\;\;s.t.\;\;m\le f(x_3)<\min\left\{m-\frac{1}{3}\;,\;f(x_2)\right\}\;,\ldots\;\text{etc}$$

Show now the sequence $\,\{x_n\}\,$ fulfills the required conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous and $X$ is compact, we have $f(X)$ is compact. Hence $f(X)$ is bounded, so $\inf f(X)$ is finite. Since $f(X)$ is closed, we have $(\inf f(X)) \in f(X)$. Consequently there exists some $\bar{x} \in X$ such that $f(\bar{x}) = \inf f(X)$.

For (i), take the sequence $x_n = \bar{x}$. For (ii), well, we have already found $\bar{x}$.

**Aside**: To clarify why $(\inf f(X)) \in f(X)$; suppose $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact, and let $s = \inf S$. Consider the sets $A_n = [s,s+ \frac{1}{n}] \cap S$. Each $A_n$ is a closed subset of $A$, and for any $N$, the set $\cap_{n=1}^N A_n$ is non-empty (otherwise this would contradict $s$ being the infimum). Since $S$ is compact, $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is also non-empty, and since $\cap_{n=1}^\infty [s,s+ \frac{1}{n}] = \{s\}$, we must have $s \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n \subset S$.

**Another aside**: (To address a shortcoming pointed out by Don Antonio.) A compact set $S$ is closed. To see this, suppose $x \notin S$. For each $s \in S$, we can find an open ball $U_s$ around $s$ and an open ball $ V_s$ of $x$ such that $U_s \cap V_s = \emptyset$. The collection $\{U_s\}_{s \in S}$ is an open cover of $S$, so has a finite subcover $U_{s_1},...,U_{s_n}$ such that $S \subset \cup_k U_{s_k}$. The set $W = \cap_k V_{s_k}$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, and it is easy to see that $W \cap S = \emptyset$. Hence the complement of $S$ is open, which means that $S$ is closed.

Comment: I highly doubt the OP already knows what you wrote, which is equivalent to Weierstrass's theorems (cont. function on compact set is bounded and attains there both its max. and min.), otherwise his question is almost trivial

Comment: @DonAntonio: Well, she has already shown that the infimum is finite, so boundedness doesn't need to appear. And in the question she mentions that $f(X)$ is compact, so that is known. The only uncertainty is (i) whether or not the equivalence with the finite intersection property is known,  and (ii) whether or not it is known that a compact set is closed.

Comment: @DonAntonio: In addition, there is http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344929/if-x-is-compact-and-fx-to-mathbbr-is-continuous-then-f-attains-the-val. The point of my post was really that the sequence can be a constant one.

Answer (score 0):

$f(X)$ is compact whence $m\in f(X),$ since $m\notin f(X)\implies m$ is a limit point of $f(X)$.

So $\exists ~\overline x\in X$ such that $f(\overline x)=m.$

Now to prove $1$, simply take $x_n=\overline x.$